# Inputting sentences into web page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have made a form, where what you type into the text box, appears on screen when you press go, only it's not working, here is the JavaScript code:
    var sentence1;
    var sentence2;
    var middlesentence;

```
function paraFunction(setence1, middlesentence, setence2)
{
sentence1 = "You plan is to ";
sentence2 = " and you must succeed at all costs";
middlesentence = form.strPara.value;
paraShow();
}

function paraShow()
{
document.getElementById('paraAns').innerHTML = (sentence1 + middlesentence + sentence2);
}
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div id="innerbody">
</div>
<h1>Testing Parameters</h1>
<p>In this example, I will be testing parameters, below you will see a form, asking you to enter a sentence, little do you know, that when you click on the form button, a sentence will be completed below, with your sentence in the middle... oops!</p>
<form type="paraForm" method="get">
<input type="text" placeholder="Input your sentence here" id="strPara"/>
<input type="button" value="Go!" name="paraFunction" onClick="paraFunction(this.form);"/>
</form>
<p id="paraAns"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your problem is with scope. `sentence1` and all of the other variables are out of the scope of the second function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass those sentences variables into `paraShow`

```
function paraFunction(setence1, middlesentence, setence2) {
    sentence1 = "You plan is to ";
    sentence2 = " and you must succeed at all costs";
    middlesentence = form.strPara.value;
    paraShow(sentence1, middlesentence, sentence2);
}

function paraShow(sentence1, middlesentence, sentence2) {
    document.getElementById('paraAns').innerHTML = (sentence1 + middlesentence + sentence2);
}
```

Comment: that didn't do it unfortunately, nothing happens when you press 'Go!'

Answer (score 0):

There were quite a few issues with this code.  First, your paraFunction declaration and your call had different parameters.  Second, you named the button paraFunction (which is probably not a breaking change, only confusing).  Third, you attempted to access strPara using form.strPara, which doesn't work because you don't have a form called form.  Once those were cleared up, the code works ok:

```
function paraFunction() {
    sentence1 = "You plan is to ";
    sentence2 = " and you must succeed at all costs";
    middlesentence = document.getElementById('strPara').value;
    paraShow();
}

function paraShow() {
    document.getElementById('paraAns').innerHTML = (sentence1 + middlesentence + sentence2);
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="innerbody">
</div>
<h1>
    Testing Parameters</h1>
<p>
    In this example, I will be testing parameters, below you will see a form, asking
    you to enter a sentence, little do you know, that when you click on the form button,
    a sentence will be completed below, with your sentence in the middle... oops!</p>
<form type="paraForm" method="get">
<input type="text" placeholder="Input your sentence here" id="strPara" />
<input type="button" value="Go!" name="paraFun" onclick="paraFunction();" />
</form>
<p id="paraAns">
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with scoping and the way the function call has been made. See the comments

```
function paraFunction(setence1, middlesentence, setence2)
{
    /* The function is called as 'paraFunction(this.form)' */
    /* At this time the value of the three arguments will be */
    /* setence1 = this.form */
    /* middlesentence = setence2 = undefined */

    /* This will create a variable 'sentence1' in global scope */
    /* name of the local variable is setence1 and not sentence1 */
    sentence1 = "You plan is to ";

    /* This will create a variable 'sentence2' in global scope */ 
    sentence2 = " and you must succeed at all costs"; 

    /* variable middlesentence is in local scope. won't be accessible outside */
     /* form is not defined in this scope, it should have been setence1 */
     middlesentence = form.strPara.value; 
     paraShow();
}

function paraShow()
{
 /*sentence1 and sentence2 will be accessible to this function but not middlesentence */        
 document.getElementById('paraAns').innerHTML = (sentence1 + middlesentence + sentence2);
}
```

There are multiple ways to solve your problem

Change the name of second argument in the paraFunction. (say middlesetence). Though this is a bad solution since one should minimize the use of global variables (in the window scope, in case of browsers). Also it doesn't make sense to pass arguments in a function which you are not using.

```
function paraFunction(setence1, middlesetence, setence2)
{
    sentence1 = "You plan is to ";
    sentence2 = " and you must succeed at all costs";
    middlesentence = setence1.strPara.value;
    paraShow();
 }

 function paraShow()
 {
     document.getElementById('paraAns').innerHTML = (sentence1 + middlesentence + sentence2);
 }
```

Modify the two functions to accept the correct parameters and use local variables like this.

```
function paraFunction(form)
{
    var sentence1 = "You plan is to ";
    var sentence2 = " and you must succeed at all costs";
    var middlesentence = form.strPara.value;
    paraShow(sentence1,middlesentence,sentence2);
 }

 function paraShow(sentence1,middlesentence,sentence2)
 {
     document.getElementById('paraAns').innerHTML = (sentence1 + middlesentence + sentence2);
 }
```

you need to change the name of the button as well.